# gRPC authorization approach

Tags: authentication, go, authorization, jwt, grpc

I work on go grpc service and implementing authorization. Literally, have to allow or forbid access to gprc methods base on JWT claims.

I do JWT parsing on `grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor` level - extracting claims and populate context with value, unauthenticated if there is no jwt or it is incorrect.

```
func (s *Server) GetSomething(ctx context.Context, req *GetSomething Request) (*GetSomething Response, error) {
    if hasAccessTo(ctx, req.ID) {
        //some work here
    }
}

func hasAccessTo(ctx context.Context, string id) {
    value := ctx.Value(ctxKey).(MyStruct)
    //some work here

}
```

So I wonder if there is some common practice for authorization/authentication to avoid boilerplate code in each grpc server method?

Comment: maybe the architecture of [go-kit](https://github.com/go-kit/kit) can help you structure your service.

Comment: I've seen something similar, where the boilerplate was put in a library, providing a wrapper function for the handler func. Then there was a policy system of a sort, that every endpoint defines the permission required, which permissions were mapped to a role (based on the identity claim from the JWT).

Comment: If you are protecting every call then yes use a `UnaryInterceptor`. I can provide an example if you need one that would work

Comment: @Varcorb if you can publish it would be nice

Comment: There's an oauth example here that might help: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/authentication

Answer (score 4):

You can call a to a `UnaryInterceptor` like so if you want to verify the jwt on every request

```
// middleware for each rpc request. This function verifies the client has the correct "jwt".
func authInterceptor(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, _ *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (interface{}, error) {
    meta, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    if !ok {
        return nil, status.Error(codes.Unauthenticated, "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR")
    }
    if len(meta["jwt"]) != 1 {
        return nil, status.Error(codes.Unauthenticated, "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR")
    }

    // if code here to verify jwt is correct. if not return nil and error by accessing meta["jwt"][0]

    return handler(ctx, req) // go to function.
}
```

In your `context` from the client use the [metadata](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/metadata) to pass the `jwt` string and verify.

In Your main function remember to register it like so

```
// register server
myService := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.UnaryInterceptor(authInterceptor), // use auth interceptor middleware
)
pb.RegisterTheServiceServer(myService, &s)
reflection.Register(myService)
```

Your client would need to call your server like this:

```
// create context with token and timeout
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(metadata.NewOutgoingContext(context.Background(), metadata.New(map[string]string{"jwt": "myjwtstring"})), time.Second*1)
defer cancel()
```

Comment: Thanks, I do pretty much the same in my interceptor. But I am looking for a more advanced approach then just check is there `jwt` or not.
I am looking for some kind of authorization:
is that user allowed go to that method

Comment: @SergiiGetman - his answer ignores the `*grpc.UnaryServerInfo` which get's passed into the function, but it contains information which I think would be useful for your purposes.  for example, it has a .FullMethod property which would allow you perform different authorization logic per method.